# Algorithms/theory behind predictive autocomplete?

Tags: algorithm, text, autocomplete, nlp, probability

Simple word autocomplete just displays a list of words that match the characters that were already typed. But I would like to order the words in the autocomplete list according to the probability of the words occuring, depending on the words that were typed before, relying on a statistical model of a text corpus. What algorithms and data structures do I need for this? Can you give me links for good tutorials?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Peter norvig had an article [How to Write a Spelling Corrector](http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html) that explains how Google's *Did you mean...?* feature works that uses Bayesian inference to make it effective. It is a very good read, and should be adaptable to an autocomplete feature.

Comment: Using Bayes' law will be overkill for autocompletion, though, since the ; just giving the most common autocompletion of a partial string is often good enough.

Comment: @larsmans True, it maybe overkill. But finding words matching the autocomplete text and sorting them according to probability just seems _so_ simple ;)

Comment: sorting them by frequency is much simpler.

Comment: #4 of the improvements points me in the right direction: Using n-grams for predictions.

Answer (score 14):

You don't need probability for autocompletion. Instead, build a [prefix tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) (aka a *trie*) with the words in the corpus as keys and their frequencies as values. When you encounter a partial string, walk the trie as far as you can, then generate all the suffixes from the point you've reached and sort them by frequency.

When a user enters a previously unseen string, just add it to the trie with frequency one; when a user enters a string that you had seen (perhaps by selecting it from the candidate list), increment its frequency.

[Note that you can't do the simple increment with a probability model; in the worst case, you'd have to recompute all the probabilities in the model.]

If you want to delve deeper into this kind of algorithms, I highly suggest you read (the first chapters of) [*Speech and Language Processing*](http://www.cs.colorado.edu/~martin/slp.html) by Jurafsky and Martin. It treats discrete probability for language processing in quite some detail.

Comment: Although a straightforward approach, this solution doesn't take into account information from n-gram language models of the corpus. i.e. word history

Comment: @swami: that's right, but is that a problem? Frequencies can be weighted if required, perhaps using an exponential scheme, so that the user's typing will outweigh the corpus or vice versa.

Comment: > "then generate all the suffixes from the point you've reached and sort them by frequency". I think there must be some important optimisations. It is impossible to traverse an entire trie given just one (or 2, or even 3) first characters. I suppose there should be a pre-computation phase...